# How do you set a individual html meta description when redirected by login_required?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I use the decorator [login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required). If I do a search via Google the link to the restricted page has the html meta description etc. from the login template and I think it's quite bad to have a description for all restricted links like "Access denied!" displayed in Google.

How do you set individual meta tags (like description) when the page is restricted by login_required?

Comment: Did you hear robots.txt ? Don't need meta tags for this issue.

Comment: @IvanBarayev Yes, but with robots.txt you can only stop the search engine bot to crawl the restricted pages, isn't it? Google lists my links in quick-access format (like if you enter amazon.com in the search field) and I like this but there should be a better description than "Access denied!"

Comment: I use Google Search Console (old name webmasters) to delete links from search result. I try this 3 solutions together -> robots.txt + search console + sitemap.xml. its work for me